# Haskell - separate a list of pairs in two lists using fold

Tags: list, haskell, fold

So, I am given a list containing tuples and I need to break it down into two lists, the first list containing the elements with odd index and the second list containing the elements with even index, must be done using fold, here is my attempt:

```
breakList :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> [[(Integer, Integer)]]
breakList [] = [[], []]
breakList xxs@(x:xs) = foldl (\ acc y -> if length (acc !! 0) < length (acc !! 1) then y : (acc !! 0) else y : (acc !! 1)  )  [[], []] xxs
```

Error I am getting:

**Couldn't match type '(Integer, Integer)'
 with '[(Integer, Integer)]'
      Expected type: [[(Integer, Integer)]]**

when hovering over `y : (acc !! 1) and y : (acc !! 0)`

Example:

Input:

> ex1 = [ (2, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (0, 2), (2, 1), (1, 4)
>   , (2, 0), (1, 2), (3, 1), (1, 0)]

Output

> breakList ex1 
>   ==  ( [(2,2),(2,3),(3,5),(2,1),(2,0),(3,1)] , [(1,3),(2,4),(0,2),(1,4),(1,2),(1,0)])

Comment: Given the output is a 2-tuple, the result of `breakList []` should be `([], [])`. But this should be handled by the `foldr` as well.

Comment: Hint: each time "swap" the lists in the 2-tuple, and append the current element to one of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you want to split a list into two lists of a pair, so the return type should be

```
([(Integer, Integer)], [(Integer, Integer)])
```

not

```
[[(Integer, Integer)]]
```

and access the element of pair, you can use `fst` and `snd` instead of through index, and finally, use `foldl` will return the resulted list in reversed order, it can be fixed use `foldr` instead. The correction look like:

```
breakList :: [(Integer, Integer)]->([(Integer, Integer)], [(Integer, Integer)])
breakList xxs = foldr (\y acc-> if length (fst acc) < length (snd acc)
                                then (y:(fst acc), snd acc)
                                else (fst acc, y:(snd acc)) ) ([], []) xxs
```

Comment: this isn't very good. repeated use of `length` (to measure lists you yourself are creating) makes it quadratic. and of course needlessly strict - it won't work on infinite lists.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, you are right. But I just correct the error of the question and don't want to modify too much of original coding in question.

Answer (score 2):

The standard trick here, as hinted at by Willem in the comments, which I first saw few years back on SO in an (F# or Ocaml) answer by [user:Ed'ka], is

```
evenodds :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
evenodds xs = foldr g ([],[]) xs
  where
  g x ~(as,bs) = (bs,x:as)
```

or

```
oddevens :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
oddevens xs = foldr g ([],[]) xs
  where
  g x ~(bs,as) = (x:as,bs)
```

What are odd positions from here, are even positions from the position one  notch further on the list.

The tilde `~` introduces a lazy pattern so that the function is properly lazy in its operations.